# What are the benefits of configuring rsync with rsync shares vs. without?

Tags: linux, centos6, rsync

I know there are two or more methods of working with `rsync`:

The first one requires that rsync would be installed on the destination machine and then you can run something like that:

```
rsync -avz file username@machine_ip:/path/to/destination
```

And I know another method, the one which requires you to configure `/etc/rsyncd.conf` at the destination machine and set up "rsync shares".

Example:

```
[test]
        comment = /tmp/test
        path = /tmp/test 
        read only = no
        list = yes
        uid = 10155
        gid = 10015
        auth users = appadmin
        secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
        hosts allow = 10.13.1.1
```

Then the command would look like that:

```
rsync -raPv files rsync://appadminp@10.13.1.2/rsync_share --password-file /etc/rsync.passwd
```

My aim is to sync between two directories while destination machine is a remote one.

I wanted to know what are the benefits of each method and what is the recommended way to use `rsync`?

Comment: the 2nd method is not using encryption

Comment: well, both methods in the original question do not use encryption :)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26182/what-is-the-need-for-rsync-server-in-daemon-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach allows you to control what you are synching from the clinet side.

The second approach configures an rsync "server" that controls what you are able to sync.

There is a third approach and I'm using it instead: rsync-over-ssh (rsync -e ssh [rest of the options]) and there is a trick that you can limit what actually can be retrieved on the server side.  I usually test the sync normally over ssh, then when I'm happy with the result I run the same command through strace (strace -f -s512 -o ~/strace.log -eexecve rsync ...).  The strace.log file will contain a line that rsync is executing via ssh, grab the line and add it to remote's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys as command="rsync_line_goes_here" in front of the corresponding key :).  From that point on the rsync configuration is "locked" and will allow only that configuration to be used over that link.

Comment: Cool trick, I'll try it.

Comment: Can you explain this in greater detail?

Comment: Depends on what part you want to be explained :)